# Javascript - how to take array of abbreviated days and output full name of days

Tags: javascript, arrays, days

I am trying to take a report of class meeting days in abbreviated form. Each row has an array of days (M,T,W,TH,F,S,SU). How could I loop through the array and change each value of:

M to Monday
T to Tuesday
W to Wednesday
TH to Thursday
F to Friday
S to Saturday
SU to Sunday

I would like to keep the array intact. To switch from {M,W,F} to {Monday,Wednesday,Friday}.

I have tried to for loop through and use a switch in the loop with no luck.

Can you help?

Comment: Tradition is...show your code and what you tried. :) Way more likely to get help here that way.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a constant map to help me translate from short to long.

Like this:

```js
const DAYS_SHORT_TO_LONG = {
  SU: 'Sunday',
  M: 'Monday',
  T: 'Tuesday',
  W: 'Wednesday',
  TH: 'Thursday',
  F: 'Friday',
  S: 'Saturday',
}

const daysToConvert = ['M', 'SU', 'F', 'TH'];

const result = daysToConvert.map((shortDay) => DAYS_SHORT_TO_LONG[shortDay]);

console.log(result);
```